# How To add Multiple LinearLayout Programatically same as existing one

Tags: android, android-layout

Snapshot of Xml:
[image]

I just want to add same child LinearLayout into Parent LinearLayout multiple times as per user requirements using **for loop** with same contents as child(i have added some TextView and ImageView to child LinearLayout);

```
public class ListData extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout childLL,parentLL;
    TextView tName,tEmail,tCity;
    ImageView iImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_data);

    parentLL=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentList);
    childLL=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.childList);
    tName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.listName);
    tEmail=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.listEmail);
    tCity=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.listCity);
    iImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.listImage);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        //parentLL.addView(childLL);
       //please Suggest code 
    }
}

}
```

Comment: use recycleview or list view instead of for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move childLayout to a separate layout file and add it manually.
Let's the new layout file is called `child_layout`, the sample code could be like:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
for (int i = 0, i < maxSize, i++) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);
    //customise your child view here if needed.
    parentLL.addView(v);
}
```